# Help SIM5320 Breakout Board construction for Raspberry Pi model B

Tags: raspberry-pi, gsm, gprs

[image]

I need a breakout board based on SIM5320 for experimenting web server http requests. I've found the board shown above in adafruit library and thought of using it as reference and slim it down to the requirements by removing unwanted circuitry.As marked in the pic, all the circuits marked with cross are not needed. And the component to which the arrow mark is pointing is the one I need to know how to create one similar to it in Altium or Eagle cad. I see it says GPS BIAS with 33nH inductor and not sure what those half rounded pads with pin nos connected to or the component type used.

Also for this board I'll be using 9V external voltage source along with LDO circuit as mentioned in the SIM5320 [Datasheet](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/SIM5320_Hardware%20Design_V1.07.pdf).I've calculated the required resistances to be used to get the desired LDO output voltage. Also I will be be using all 3 protocols (UART, SPI, I2C) and for these I will be putting separated headers so that I can use the desired ones when needed.I hope that should be enough to RPi to take care of SIM5320 . Need some one to check my approach and let me know If there are any other changes to be done in the circuitry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That component is a [solder jumper](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8589/choosing-configuration-jumpers-solder-bridges-0-ohm-resistors-dip-switches) to enable optional antenna power. Meaning, it is a special footprint on your PCB that can be easily bridged with solder in order to make a connection. Alternatively, you can remove the solder the break the connection. Solder jumpers are commonly used for board configuration when they are a connection that will be rarely changed.

I haven't used Eagle in a while, but IIRC Sparkfun distributes an Eagle library which includes the above symbol and a footprint or two for solder jumpers. If you don't want to bother, you could also use a resistor in the schematic (0Ω, DNP) and set it as an 0402 or 0603 footprint. Then a zero ohm resistor or small bit of wire can be used. Making your own footprint is also an option.

See page 48 of the [datasheet](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/SIM5320_Hardware%20Design_V1.07.pdf). It shows an application circuit for both an active and passive antenna. If you know you are only going to be using a passive antenna, you can eliminate the circuit beyond the solder jumper (all you need is the antenna connector and a tuning network, which the Adafruit schematic doesn't seem to include).

Regarding your other circuitry: if you aren't using the LiPo battery stuff, and no microphone, then removing those blocks is fine. As long as all your logic I/O is 3V3, then removing the level shifting is also fine.

Comment: Oh i see. Thanks for pointing.I really don't need the active antenna for this project so I'll eliminate for now. And what about that 33nH inductor in that circuit, is it a normal type or any special?. Also please check with my approach and let me know If I need to do any changes.

Comment: If you are eliminating the active antenna capability, you don't need the inductor. As far as its value/type, the datasheet describes it as "bead" so the value is probably non-critical (it is just to block RF between the regulator and the antenna).

Comment: Thanks. Even I thought it would be some kind of ferrite bead. Anyways I'll eliminate. What do you think of my approach will that enough to interface the SIM5320 to RPi?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the SIM5320, but if you have the UART, SPI, and I2C broken out, I would imagine that's more than sufficient to interface it with the Pi.

Comment: Thats fine.Even I'm thinking of the same way. Because all those level shifting circuits are for arduino and for Pi there is no need of it. So direct connections from GPIOs should be fine. Anyways I'll take care of it. Thank you very much for your time and support.